# Lines not tangent as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two concentric circles centered at `O` drawn. Chords `LM` and `MN` of the bigger circle are tangent to the smaller circle at `S` and `T`.  The measures of `angle{SOM}` and `angle{TOM}` are congruent and have measure 80 degrees. According to the Power-of-a-Point Theorem, if the radius of the smaller circle
is`r`, `|OM| = r + x`, and `|MS| = |MT| = y`,

`y² = x(x + 2r)`.

So, if `r = 3/4` and `x = 3/2`, `y = (3*sqrt{2})/2`.  Since `triangle{LOM}` is congruent to `triangle{NOM}`, `OM` bisects `angle{M}`.

`angle{LMO} = angle{SMO} = 180 - (80 + 90) = 10`,

and

`angle{NMO} = angle{TMO} = 180 - (80 + 90) = 10`.

I have all this coded in the following `TikZ` diagram.  Why are the chords not tangent to the smaller circle at `S` and `T`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%Two concentric circles are drawn.
%
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (O) circle (3/4);
\draw (O) circle (9/4);
%
\coordinate (S) at (100:3/4);
\draw[fill] (S) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (T) at (-100:3/4);
\draw[fill] (T) circle (1.5pt);
%
\coordinate (M) at (-9/4,0);
%
\coordinate (L) at ($(M) +(20:{3*sqrt(2)})$);
\coordinate (N) at ($(M) +(-20:{3*sqrt(2)})$);
%
\draw (M) -- (L);
\draw (M) -- (N);

%The labels for the points are typeset.
\path node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(O) +(0.15,0)$){$O$};
\path node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(M) +(-0.15,0)$){$M$};
\path node[anchor={20+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(L) +(20:0.15)$){$L$};
\path node[anchor={-20+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(N) +(-20:0.15)$){$N$};
\path node[anchor={80-180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(S) +(80:0.15)$){$S$};
\path node[anchor={-80+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(T) +(-80:0.15)$){$T$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In your comments, you state that the radius of the bigger circle is `1/sin(10)`, but you have `\draw[name path=bigger_circle] (O) circle ({cot(10)})`.  So, your bigger circle is a bit small.

Comment: Draw the bigger circle with `\draw (O) circle ({1/sin(10)})`. Locate `M` with `\coordinate (M) at ({-1/sin(10)},0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The starting magic number 80° for angles SOM and TOM is wrong, if you want to have tangents. The angle can be easily calculated by looking at the triangle OSM with one orthogonal angle at the tangent point S (the result is about 70.5°).

Also I would calculate the coordinates of L and N as polar coordinates with origin O. This can again be done looking at the triangle OLS that also has a orthogonal angle at the tangent point S.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro\BigRadius{9/4}
\pgfmathsetmacro\SmallRadius{3/4}
% \Angle is the angle part of the polar coordinate of S with origin O
% 180 - acos(\SmallRadius/\BigRadius} = 109.47102
\pgfmathsetmacro\Angle{180 - acos(1/3)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\AngleTwo{2*\Angle - 180}

% Coordinates
\path
  coordinate (O) at (0, 0)
  coordinate (S) at (\Angle:\SmallRadius)
  coordinate (T) at (-\Angle:\SmallRadius)
  coordinate (M) at (-\BigRadius, 0)
  coordinate (L) at (\AngleTwo:\BigRadius)
  coordinate (N) at (-\AngleTwo:\BigRadius)
;

% Two concentric circles and lines
\draw[line join=bevel]
  (O) circle[radius=\SmallRadius]
  (O) circle[radius=\BigRadius]
  (L) -- (M) -- (N)
;

% Points
\fill[radius=1.5pt]
  \foreach \p in {O, S, T, M, L, N} { (\p) circle[] }
;

% The labels
\path[inner sep=0pt, node font=\footnotesize]
  node[anchor=west] at ($(O) +(0.1,0)$){$O$}
  node[anchor=east] at ($(M) +(-0.15,0)$){$M$}
  node[anchor={\AngleTwo+180}] at ($(L) +(20:0.15)$){$L$}
  node[anchor={-\AngleTwo+180}] at ($(N) +(-20:0.15)$){$N$}
  node[anchor={\Angle-180}] at ($(S) +(80:0.15)$){$S$}
  node[anchor={-\Angle+180}] at ($(T) +(-80:0.15)$){$T$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Big radius and angle are given

The small radius can be calculated with the right triangle MSO. Because the example above has used macros, only the macro definitions for `\Angle` and `\SmallRadius` need to be changed:

```
\def\Angle{100}
\pgfmathsetmacro\BigRadius{9/4}
% \Angle is the angle part of the polar coordinate of S with origin O
% Then the small radius can be calculated:
% \SmallRadius = \BigRadius * cos(180 - \Angle) = 0.3907
\pgfmathsetmacro\SmallRadius{\BigRadius * cos(180 - \Angle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\AngleTwo{2*\Angle - 180}
```

> [image: Result with angle 100]

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  You helped me find my mistake in calculations.

Comment: I have edited the code and get the appropriate points of tangency.  Now, the lengths of `LM` and `NM` are a bit too long.  Is this just an error from the `calc` package?

Comment: I do need the measures of angles `SOM` and `TOM` to be 80 degrees. Triangle `OSM` and triangle`OTM` are congruent, right triangles. So, `OM` bisects angle`LMN`, and angle `LMO` and angle `NMO` both have measure 10 degrees.

Comment: r is the radius of the smaller circle. According to the Law of Sines, |OM| = r/sin(10). By the Pythagorean Theorem,
|MS| = |MT| = r*cot(10).

Comment: I posted a response with the edited code.  In it, I use `r=1`.  I am using this code mostly to see how accurate the `calc` package is.  Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire If the angle is given, then the smaller radius can be calculated, see the updated answer.

Comment: Your code does draw `LM` and `MN` the appropriate length and tangent to the smaller circle.  I agree.  The smaller circle is too small, though - the label `O` for the center of the circle is touching the circle.

Comment: Here is my concern.  I should be able to start with declaring the radius of the smaller circle as `1cm`.  Now that the calculations are correct in my updated post with the specified radius, why are the chords drawn too long?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire "O" touching is fixed. The radius of the smaller circle is not sufficient to specify the problem. At least the radius of the bigger circle or the angle is needed. If two values are specified, the third can then be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an edited version of the code from my post.  I corrected an error in a calculation that Heiko Oberdiek spied.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

%Two concentric circles are drawn. $\angle{LMN}$ is an angle inscribed in the bigger circle; its measure is
%20 degrees. The chords are tangent to the smaller circle at S and T. $\triangle{OSM}$ and $\triangle{OTM}$
%are congruent, right triangles. So, OM bisects $\angle{LMN}$, and $\angle{LMO}$ and $\angle{NMO}$ both
%have measure 10 degrees.
%
%r is the radius of the smaller circle. According to the Law of Sines, |OM| = r/sin(10). By the Pythagorean Theorem,
%|MS| = |MT| = (r/sin(10))sqrt{1-sin^{2}(10)} = r*cot(10).
%
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (O) circle (1);
\draw (O) circle ({cot(10)});
%
\coordinate (S) at (100:1);
\draw[fill] (S) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (T) at (-100:1);
\draw[fill] (T) circle (1.5pt);
%
\coordinate (M) at ({-cot(10)},0);
%
\coordinate (L) at ($(M) +(10:{2*cot(10)})$);
\coordinate (N) at ($(M) +(-10:{2*cot(10)})$);
%
\draw (M) -- (L);
\draw (M) -- (N);

%The labels for the points are typeset.
\path node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(O) +(0.15,0)$){$O$};
\path node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(M) +(-0.15,0)$){$M$};
\path let \p1=($(L)-(M)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(L) +({\n1}:0.15)$){$L$};
\path let \p1=($(M)-(N)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(N) +({\n1}:0.15)$){$N$};
\path node[anchor={80-180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(S) +(80:0.15)$){$S$};
\path node[anchor={-80+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(T) +(-80:0.15)$){$T$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek  Thanks for adding the figure to my post.  You can see my concerns with the improper lengths of the chords from it.

Comment: The comments correctly state the formula for the radius of the bigger circle: `R = |OM| = r/sin(10) = 1/sin(10)` with smaller radius `r = 1`. The TeX code, however, uses `cot(10)` ( = `cos(10)/sin(10)`) instead. Then it follows that `|MS| = sqrt(R² - r²) = sqrt[1/sin²(10) - 1] = sqrt[sin²(10) -1] / sin(10)`.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek  And `sqrt[1 - sin^{2}(10) -] = cos(10)`.

Comment: Summary: Your example if fixed, if the bigger radius is set to the `1/sin(10)` and the position of `M` is corrected accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I did not implement the calculations that I had made.